# Make a wx.Panel have a specific width and height inside a wx.Frame (wxPython - wxWidgets)

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to get a wx.Panel of a given size inside a wx.Frame.

I have tried the following code, to clearly specify wx.Panel size without success.

When I run the application, I get that the wx.Panel has larger width than 100 pixels.

[Actual wx.Panel width is about 125pixels instead of 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtUPO.png)

Could someone help me to identify what is not properly used here?

```
#!/bin/env python
import wx

# App Class
class MyAppTest6(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):

        frame = AppFrame(title = u'Hello World', pos=(50, 60), size=(150, 250))
        frame.Show()
        #self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

# Form Panel, 300 pixels Panel
class Form(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(100, 100))

        self.SetBackgroundColour('RED')
        self.SetInitialSize(
            (100,100)
        )
        self.SetSize(
            (100,100)
        )

# AppFrame
class AppFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title, pos, size)

        # Define color
        self.SetBackgroundColour('LIGHTGREY')

        # Add elements
        self.form = Form(self)

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        sizer.Add(self.form, 0, wx.CENTER)
        sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = MyAppTest6(False)
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

AS you see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427319/set-wx-frame-size-wxpython-wxwidgets) question you can add this before your call to app.MainLoop():

```
import wx.lib.inspection
wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
```