# Set wx.Frame size (wxPython - wxWidgets)

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am new to wxPython and I am finding some issues while seting a given size for both frames and windows (widgets). I have isolated the issue to the simplest case where I try to create a Frame of 250x250 pixels.

Running the code I get a window of an actual size of 295 width by 307 height (taking into consideration the Windows´s top window bar)

I am using Python 2.7 in Windows 10.

What am I missing?

```
#!/bin/env python
import wx

# App Class
class MyAppTest7(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):

        frame = AppFrame(title = u'Hello World', pos=(50, 60), size=(250, 250))
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

# AppFrame
class AppFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id=-1, title=title, pos=pos, size=size)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = MyAppTest7(False)
        app.MainLoop()
```

An addtional test to further show issue:

```
#!/bin/env python
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, title="The Main Frame")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show(True)
        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(400,100), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, name="MyFrame"):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

And the result:

As you can see displayed window (frame) has 482 pixels (-see Paint's bottom bar-) instead of the expected 400.

[Window size measured in pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtsvE.png)

Comment: How do you measure the dimensions of Frame?

Comment: I take a screenshot in Windows 10 using Alt + PrintScreen key. Then I just measure width in Paint.

Comment: Take your screen size and make that the width of the frame, then use `print self.frame.GetSize()` and see what you get.

Comment: I set up width to 1920 pixels. I got an actual width of 1911, and I got 1552 from print self.frame.GetSize()

Comment: My text scale was set up to 125% (1920x1080 in a 15.6" laptop screen). If I setup text scale to 100% then I got an actual width of 1906 pixels and wxPython reports 1932 from print self.frame.GetSize(). This is weird and it seems like wxPython is not being able to get the right size of things in my particular laptop (Windows 10)

Comment: Additionally I do self.Maximize(True) in the wx.Frame class so the Frame is maximized on startup. Then I get 1920 pixels actual width (as expected, as my LCD is 1920 pixels width) but print self.frame.GetSize() reports 1932 pixels. Is wxPython actually compatible with Windows 10?

Answer (score 5):

Add this before your call to `app.MainLoop()`:

```
import wx.lib.inspection
wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
```

That will let you easily see the actual size (and other info) for each widget in the application, like this:

[image: Widget Inspection Tool]